# How do I jump to location of the Header in the Timeline?

Tags: animation, timeline

When my timeline is expanded and I play an animation for a little while then the header goes off to the right and I don't see it anymore.  Is there a hot key to jump to the location of the header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press numpad <kbd>0</kbd>.....................

[image]

Me wearing the motion cap for the hand animation above:

[image]

Comment: I love that finger. We have a Michelangelo in the making! :D

Comment: Thanks, yes, good point, this was my inspiration!

Comment: is the hand rigged? :D

Comment: @Chris We are working on it, motion capture and everything, please stay tuned!!

Comment: Leonardo di Caprio is ok to play the hand

Comment: can i have a picture of you wearing the full body mocap suit? 

Comment: sure, here we go